# Spring Boot Spring Data JPA and Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am very familiar with "legacy" Spring 4 applications.  By "legacy" I mean without using Spring Boot and using application-context.xml files along with annotations.   However, I am a newbie with Spring Boot and Configuration classes.

I am creating a new Spring Boot application, and moving some code to my old Spring application to this new Spring Boot app.   With that I am implementing Spring Data JPA along with that?

I already had the entities, so I just brought that in.   I have an application.properties setup correctly.  I created the repositories as described in all the examples I saw, and so I had a repository that looks like this:

```
@Repository("contactDao")
public interface ContactDao extends CrudRepository<ContactEntity, Long>
{
}
```

So, as I understand it, there are numerous functions to findOne(Long id), and findAll(), etc .... All these methods are build in.    I was even able to unit test reading, writing to the database, and that all worked great.

So, I am now wondering ... do I need to create the implementation?   I mean since I don't have an EntityManager ... do I need one?

All the examples I am seeing now, show an interface like the one above, but without the @Repository annotation:

```
 public interface ContactDao extends CrudRepository<ContactEntity, Long>
 {
 }
```

And I am now seeing examples that require an implementation:

```
@Repository("contactDao")
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao 
{
    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;    

    @Override
    public ContactEntity findOne(Long contactId)
    {
          return entityManager.findOne(contactId);
    }
}
```

I thought the promise of Spring Data JPA was to not have to have an Impl, but that the interface would be enough????????????

The reason that this comes up is because I am now testing my business services, and it complains that I am missing the EntityManagerFactory ... I didn't think I needed one.

Any help in clarification would be greatly appreciated.   I am looking at Google and going to all types of sites and github projects, but some of these sites and projects .... if they are not from 2017, they are most likely out of date.

I just want the correct way to build this project via current standards.

UPDATED:

1) Put back my interfaces
2) Removed the Implementation code
3) The DAO/Repository code tests fine
4) Added business Service:

```
public interface ContactService
{
    List<ContactEntity> getAllContacts();
    List<ContactEntity> getContactsByUserId(long userId);
    ContactEntity getContactById(long contactId);
    ContactEntity add(ContactEntity newContact);
    ContactEntity update(ContactEntity newContact);
    void remove(long contactId);
}
```

and here is the actual implementation of the service:

```
@Transactional
@Service("contactService")
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService
{
    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;   // THIS ERRORS

    @Override
    public List<ContactEntity> getAllContacts()
    {
        List<ContactEntity> contactList = (List<ContactEntity>) contactDao.findAll();
        return contactList;
     }

     @Override
     public List<ContactEntity> getContactsByUserId(long userId)
     {
          UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
          userEntity.setUserId(userId);
          List<ContactEntity> contactList = contactDao.findByUser(userEntity);
          return contactList;
      }

      ... other methods ...
}
```

and here is the test setup:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.tomholmes.springboot.phonebook.server")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=
{"com.tomholmes.springboot.phonebook.server"})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class TestServiceContextConfiguration
{     }

 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = TestServiceContextConfiguration.class)
 @Transactional
 public class BaseServiceImplTests
 {     }
```

Finally, here is the test itself:

```
public class ContactServiceImplTest extends BaseServiceImplTests
{
    @Autowired
    private ContactService service;

     @Test
     public void testFetchAll() throws Exception
    {
        List<ContactEntity> contactEntityList = service.getAllContacts();
        assertNotNull(contactEntityList);
     }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contactEmailService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contactEmailDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactEmailDao': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#70ab80e3' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#70ab80e3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactEmailDao': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#70ab80e3' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#70ab80e3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#70ab80e3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:448)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 65 more
```

Comment: Read the reference documentation. Not random examples (that we know nothing about). Your last example wouldn't even compile, so the source where you found it is not reliable. If you have an exception, and you want to know why, then post the error stacck trace, and the relevant code/configuration. Don't try random things or make random guesses.

Comment: You don't need the `@Repository´ annotation on Spring Data interfaces. If you see an implementation class, which uses that annotation, it's not Spring Data. See e.g. this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @JBNizet I have read the reference documentation and it is NOT crystal-clear, if it was, there wouldn't be these questions.   Yeah, I have an exception that my Service code when autowiring the ContactDao does not find the entityManagerFactoryBean ... so where is it?  It's not in the Repository, does it need to be in the Service?

Comment: Adding the @Reposity didn't seem to hurt anything, but it didn't solve my problem on where, why, how I need an EntityManagerFactory.  Like I said, I was porting this over from a legacy application and trying to learn Spring Boot from working with "legacy" Spring applications for so long.

Comment: This is one of the pages I was looking at: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-example and this one:  https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-search-example/  and this one:   https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: The "examples" are probably cargo-cult from people who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: The only link where i haven't found an obvious error is your second link (mkyong). Forget the other 2. Regarding the EntityManagerFactory, could you please post the complete error message? And also clarify, if you use this ContactDaoImpl or if ContactDao is a proper Spring Data interface?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need implement ContactDao interface.

Imagine you have a db with employees.
As an example:

```
@Repository
public interface ContactDao extends CrudRepository<ContactEntity, Long>{
    Employee findOne(Long id);
    List<Employee> findByName(String name);
    //etc...
}
```

then inside your class you implement business logic or wherever you want you can code like:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implement Service{
    Autowired
    ContactDao contactDao;

    public Employee getEmployee(Long id){
        return contactDao.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

`@Repository` or `@Service` or with other annotation, you say to Spring Boot that these are beans so it has to manage them.

For Exceptions about EntityManager read carefully the error message. Maybe something wrong about beans you create or you don't. Google it or post it.

Comment: Yep, that is what I did originally ... all interfaces, and NO implementations, and when I try to test my business services, I get a monster long error.

Comment: Then you should show us your error. Otherwise we are not able to help.

Comment: @dunni I just posted the error.... I have done this before ....  It's not often I get attitude though when I ask a question.  I thought we were here to help each other?    And it's NOT like I haven't been researching all this, and going through several books trying to find an answer for this.   When I first learned Spring, I had to do a lot of the same ... a lot of research and trial and error until I found out what all the issues were.

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.wisdom.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.wisdom.spring.model.students;
import com.wisdom.spring.repo.students_repo;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class studentController {
    @Autowired
    students_repo STDRepo;

    @GetMapping(value = "/a")
    public String a() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/save")
    public List<students> getStudents(){

        System.out.println("Data returned");
        return STDRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/savestd")
    public void saveBurger(students student) {
        STDRepo.save(student);
    }

}



package com.wisdom.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class students {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int s_id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

    public students() {

    }

    public students(int s_id, String name, String address) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }

    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}



package com.wisdom.spring.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.wisdom.spring.model.students;

public interface students_repo extends JpaRepository<students,String> {

}

//pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wisdom.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>myspringjpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-spring-jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

//application config

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/finalproject
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=8855
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8585
```